# python plotly - heatmap with different data above and below diagonal

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap based on two different matrices with identical dimensions but different data, so that the values for matrix1 are shown below the diagonal and the values for matrix2 are shown above the diagonal. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create the data
matrix1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    [0.2,np.nan,np.nan],
    [0.5,0.7,np.nan]
])
matrix2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan,20,40],
    [np.nan,np.nan,70],
    [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
])            

# plot
fig = px.imshow(matrix1)
fig.add_heatmap(z=matrix2, colorscale='Bluered')
fig.show()
```

Here is what I'm getting:
[image]

which is quite close to what I want, except that the legends overlap. How can I change the position of one of the legends? Or maybe my approach is wrong altogether?

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_x=0.8)` By specifying this, the second scale is moved; the first is at 1.0.

Comment: Thanks this works. Any way to access the position of the first scalebar, say if I want to get them both closer to the heatmap?

Comment: I thought I could adjust the color scale by specifying the name of the axis, but it did not work. I suggest a different method. Try the following code. `fig = px.imshow(matrix1, aspect='equal');fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_x=0.8)
fig.add_heatmap(z=matrix2, colorscale='Bluered');fig.data[1].colorbar.x=0.7;fig.show()`

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. Thanks again.